# MVC 4 dropdownlist selected value using enum not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

So, I have a model that contains a list of team members for a team. Each one of those team members has a list of journals associated with that member. Those journals all have a status associated with them that I use with an enum.

```
public enum DailyEntryStatus
{
    [Description("NA")]
    NA,
    [Description("Void")]
    Void,
    [Description("Submitted")]
    Submitted,
    [Description("Rejected")]
    Rejected,
    [Description("Approved")]
    Approved
};
```

My issue is, I have a dropdown on my view for each journal in a team member's journal list in the model. I am able to populate the dropdownlist with the enum values but I want that journals current status to be selected in the dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusFilter", EnumSelectListExtensions.DailyEntryStatusList(oEntry.Status), new { @class = "input-medium" })
```

I am using an extension method DailyEntryStatusList(enum status) to populate the list which takes the enum status as parameter. (oEntry.Status is the current journal status in the loop)

```
public static class EnumSelectListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DailyEntryStatusList(DailyEntryStatus eStatus)
    {
        var oList = from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof (DailyEntryStatus))
                    select new {Value = e.ToString(), Name = e.ToString()};

        return new SelectList(oList, "Value", "Name", eStatus.ToString());
    }   
 }
```

I have tried several ways to get this to work with no luck and maybe I am just going about it the wrong way. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that eStatus is being passed in correctly and that is matches one of the items in the list? Have you stepped through to make sure?

Comment: Yup, Correct status for each one is being shown.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("StatusFilter", ..` is rendering `<select name="StatusFilter" ..` and selecting the current value of the property `StatusFilter`, but I suspect that's not the fully qualified name of the property based on the fact its a collection. It should have a name something like `Journals[0].StatusFilter`. Please post the model and the loop you are using to build the view

Comment: It ended up being an issue on my side. That dropdown was being targeted in jQuery and the selected val was being defaulted to the 1st one. Just one of those days I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is you are instantiating an anonymous object where it expects an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for the list.

```
select new SelectListItem {Value = e.ToString(), Name = e.ToString()};
```

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't I get an exception of object not set to an instance of the object when its generating the list.

Comment: I believe what he is doing is valid, though obviously there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not specifically certain of what the problem with what you are doing is, but try this.

```
public static class EnumSelectListExtensions
{
    public static SelectList DailyEntryStatusList(DailyEntryStatus eStatus)
    {
         return new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(DailyEntryStatus)), eStatus.ToString());     
   }   
 }
```

Two things I did. Change the return type to a SelectList rather than a generic list of SelectListItems. The other thing is that I simplified how the enum values are loaded in to the list. Let me know if it works.

The only issue with that is that you don't specify the order that they display in, but you can change that if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Total dumb moment. Everything is working fine, It was being changed in jQuery. Actually changed the extension method to just use the actual enum status to generate the list

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj) where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                     select new { Id = e, Name = e.ToString() };
        return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
    }
```